# Is this sentence correct? Present Perfect for finished past

Tags: present-perfect

Is this sentence correct?

**"Post-Soviet Russia has long hesitated before definitively recognizing the frontiers with its new neighbors"**

The recognition comes after the hesitation; therefore, the time period for the latter is finished. Plus Russia has NOT been hesitating for some time now.

Isn't it better to say:

**"Post-Soviet Russia had long hesitated before definitively recognizing the frontiers with its new neighbors"**?

OR

**"Post-Soviet Russia hesitated for a long time before definitively recognizing the frontiers with its new neighbors"**

Comment: 'Russia has NOT been hesitating for some time now.' But had it when the statement was originally made? Your second suggestion _is_ correct **if**  made long after the period of hesitation ended. As fdb implies, it is in a rather scholarly register.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the English, but I feel bound to say that I am far from convinced that Russia has, even now, definitively recognised its frontiers. Moreover I am not sure you should use the term 'new neighbours'. There is nothing 'new' about them, they have always been there. More important still I find the statement unwieldy. My inclination would be to say 'Post-Soviet Russia remains hesitant to accept its new frontiers'. If you wish to debate with me why I think Russia is acting less unreasonably than the British government thinks it is, please do so in 'chat'.

Comment: [chat] {Russia forum}

Comment: The sentence isn't mine, and I take no responsibility for its content. I only felt that what I was reading was sort of um... vague? imprecise? since the only way the sentence is IMHO correct is if it's being said right after the recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Only the third of your suggestions is idiomatic English.